# Is `/dev/null` treated differently from other files when the `noclobber` option is set?

Tags: bash

As an experiment, I tried running `set -o noclobber` and then running `echo foo > /dev/null`.  I was able to do so; no errors were raised:

```
bash-3.2$ set -o noclobber
bash-3.2$ echo "foo" > /dev/null
bash-3.2$ echo "bar" > /dev/null
bash-3.2$ echo "baz" > /dev/null
```

However, when I tried the same thing with a file I had previously created, I saw the expected errors:

```
bash-3.2$ touch bar.txt
bash-3.2$ echo "bar" > bar.txt
bash: bar.txt: cannot overwrite existing file
```

Does `noclobber` treat the `/dev/null` file differently than it does other files?

NOTE: I understand *why* it might behave this way (i.e. because of the nature of `/dev/null` and what its purpose is), but I don't see any documentation to that effect [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).  I suppose it's possible that this is an undocumented feature, or (probably more likely) I just missed the documentation?

Comment: Section 3.6.2 says "the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file", but `/dev/null` and family are not *regular* files. IIRC they're "character special files"

Comment: That makes sense.  I did read that section when I was looking for my answer, and I also `grep`'ed for `/dev/null` on this page and didn't find it, so I assumed it was undocumented or something.  In a perfect world, the doc's author(s) could add an example of what a non-"regular file", but you're right that this phrase would explain this behavior.  Thanks!

Comment: Non-regular files are all files which are not regular files. "Non-regular" is not a standard term, files which are not regular files are called *special files*. Special files are *directories* (yes, directories are files), *symbolic links*, *named pipes* (aka FIFOs), *sockets*, *character devices* (e.g. mice), and *block devices* (e.g. disks, partitions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Section 3.6.2 Redirecting Output](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirecting-Output) says:

> If the redirection operator is ‘`>`’, and the `noclobber` option to the `set` builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and is a regular file.

But `/dev/null` and family are not *regular* files. They're "character special files":

```
$ [ -c /dev/null ] ; echo $?
0
$ [ -f /dev/null ] ; echo $?
1
```

The same applies to other non-regular files, like FIFO pipes:

```
$ mkfifo foo; set -o noclobber
$ echo > .bashrc
bash: .bashrc: cannot overwrite existing file
$ cat foo & echo a > foo
[1] 18857
a
```

(And, presumably, sockets, block devices, etc.)

Comment: And actually, the fact that the shell needs to check the type of the file first means there's a TOCTOU race and noclobber is not safe in the face of an attacker replacing a symlink to /dev/null with a symlink to another file at the right moment for instance.

Comment: I suppose the shell could work around that by opening the file first, checking the type then, and bailing out if it got a regular file, without clobbering the file. If it got a file not found, it'd try again with `O_CREAT|O_EXCL` to create it. If the file was created in between, the latter call would fail unexpected, but it'd at least be harmless (and the shell could try again from the start to see if the created file was a regular file.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: IMHO the shell should not be used to implement a security boundary in the first place, but users are probably not going to care about what I think.

Comment: Personally I don't think of `noclobber` as a security feature, but as a guardrail. Sure I can jump over the guardrail if I really want to or someone can push me over it, but those are not the situations this guardrail is meant to be guarding against.

Comment: @ilkkachu: If you were doing this for security reasons, not as muru says just as a "guard rail", another approach is `open(O_CREAT|O_WRONLY)` (*without* O_TRUNC or O_APPEND).  Then, if `fstat` tells you it was a regular file, bail out and `close`.  You might or might not `stat` first as an early out, to perhaps avoid updating timestamps.  In a related case if you wanted to truncate a regular file on after some check, you could open without truncation and then `ftruncate(fd, 0)` (POSIX.2001, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html).  Your way works, too, but has to handle races.

Comment: @PeterCordes, mm, yes, but that wouldn't tell if the `open()` call just created the file and we can continue; or if it already existed and we need to bail out? We could use `open(O_CREAT|O_EXCL)` to get a new file, but that doesn't help if we want to accept opening an existing special file. I can't think of a single combination that would accept creating a new file, opening an existing special file, but reject opening an existing regular file. And yes, well, I was thinking if it's possible to do it "right", without harmful races, regardless of if we call it "security" or not :)

Comment: @ilkkachu: Oh duh, you're right, I forgot the part where we do want to write to a regular file if we just created it!  My idea would *only* allow redirecting to special files :P  Your idea does seem workable, only ever using O_CREAT with O_EXCL being the key.  You might start with `open(O_CREAT|O_EXCL)` and fall back to `open()` *without either* (and `fstat` to check for non-regular existing file); that would optimize if the common case is redirection to a regular file.  The other order works, too, and is more efficient if you're usually redirecting to /dev/null.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yeah, if the script is supposed to do anything, the common case ought to be creating a new file. Though to be honest, if I were to implement that, I'd probably just call `stat()` first and then branch based on the result (if no file exists, create new with `O_EXCL`; if regular file exists, error; if special file exists, open with `fstat()` double-check to avoid the symlink attack) just because that would put all three cases visible in one place and I might be better able to understand the logic next year, too. :P